# Two pandas MultiIndex frames multiply every row with every row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, multi-index

I need to multiply two MultiIndexed frames (say `df1, df2`) that have the same highest level index, such that for each of the highest level index each row of `df1` is multiplied to each row of `df2` elementwise. I have implemented the following example that does what I want, however it looks pretty ugly:

```
a = ['alpha', 'beta']
b = ['A', 'B', 'C']
c = ['foo', 'bar']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4),
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                       [a, b], 
                       names=['greek', 'latin']),
                   columns=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 4]]),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, c], names=['greek', 'foobar']),
    columns=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['greek', 'latin', 'foobar', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'])

for i in df1.index.get_level_values('greek').unique():
    for j in df1.loc[i].index.get_level_values('latin').unique():
        for k in df2.loc[i].index.get_level_values('foobar').unique():
            df3 = df3.append(pd.Series([i, j, k], 
                                       index=['greek', 'latin', 'foobar']
                                       ).append(
                df1.loc[i, j] * df2.loc[i, k]), ignore_index=True)

df3.set_index(['greek', 'latin', 'foobar'], inplace=True)
```

As you can see the code is very manual that defines the columns etc manually multiple times, and sets the index in the end. Here is the input and the optput. They are correct and exactly what I want:

**df1:**

```
                   C1        C2        C3        C4
 greek latin                                        
 alpha A      0.208380  0.856373 -1.041598  1.219707
       B      1.547903 -0.001023  0.918973  1.153554
       C      0.195868  2.772840  0.060960  0.311247
 beta  A      0.690405 -1.258012  0.118000 -0.346677
       B      0.488327 -1.206428  0.967658  1.198287
       C      0.420098 -0.165721  0.626893 -0.377909,
```

**df2:**

```
                C1  C2  C3  C4
greek foobar                
 alpha foo      1   0   1   0
       bar      1   1   1   1
 beta  foo      0   0   0   0
       bar      0   2   0   4
```

**result:**

```
                           C1        C2        C3        C4
 greek latin foobar                                        
 alpha A     foo     0.208380  0.000000 -1.041598  0.000000
             bar     0.208380  0.856373 -1.041598  1.219707
       B     foo     1.547903 -0.000000  0.918973  0.000000
             bar     1.547903 -0.001023  0.918973  1.153554
       C     foo     0.195868  0.000000  0.060960  0.000000
             bar     0.195868  2.772840  0.060960  0.311247
 beta  A     foo     0.000000 -0.000000  0.000000 -0.000000
             bar     0.000000 -2.516025  0.000000 -1.386708
       B     foo     0.000000 -0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
             bar     0.000000 -2.412855  0.000000  4.793149
       C     foo     0.000000 -0.000000  0.000000 -0.000000
             bar     0.000000 -0.331443  0.000000 -1.511638
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the following solution that seems to work and provide the right outcome. While Stephen's answer remains the fastest solution, this is close enough but provides a big advantage, it works for arbitrary MultiIndexed frames, as opposed to the ones where the index is a product of lists. This was the case I needed to solve for, though the example I provided did not reflect that. Thanks to Stephen for the excellent and fast solution for that case - certainly learned a few things from that code!

**Code:**

```
dft = df2.swaplevel()
dft.sortlevel(level=0,inplace=True)
df5=pd.concat([df1*dft.loc[i,:] for i in dft.index.get_level_values('foobar').unique() ], keys=dft.index.get_level_values('foobar').unique().tolist(), names=['foobar'])
df5=df5.reorder_levels(['greek', 'latin', 'foobar'],axis=0)
df5.sortlevel(0,inplace=True)
```

**Test Data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = ['alpha', 'beta']
b = ['A', 'B', 'C']
c = ['foo', 'bar']
data_columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']
columns = ['greek', 'latin', 'foobar'] + data_columns

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(a) * len(b), len(data_columns)),
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                       [a,b], names=columns[0:2]),
                   columns=data_columns
                   )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
                             [1, 1, 1, 1],
                             [0, 0, 0, 0],
                             [0, 2, 0, 4],
                             ]),
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                       [a, c],
                       names=[columns[0], columns[2]]),
                   columns=data_columns
                   )
```

**Timing Code:**

```
def method1():
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    for i in df1.index.get_level_values('greek').unique():
            for j in df1.loc[i].index.get_level_values('latin').unique():
                for k in df2.loc[i].index.get_level_values('foobar').unique():
                    df3 = df3.append(pd.Series(
                        [i, j, k],
                        index=columns[:3]).append(
                        df1.loc[i, j] * df2.loc[i, k]), ignore_index=True)
    df3.set_index(columns[:3], inplace=True)
    return df3

def method2():
    # build an index from the three index columns
    idx = [df1.index.get_level_values(col).unique() for col in columns[:2]
           ] + [df2.index.get_level_values(columns[2]).unique()]
    size = [len(x) for x in idx]
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(idx, names=columns[:3])

    # get the indices needed for df1 and df2
    idx_a = np.indices((size[0] * size[1], size[2])).reshape(2, -1)
    idx_b = np.indices((size[0], size[1] * size[2])).reshape(2, -1)
    idx_1 = idx_a[0]
    idx_2 = idx_a[1] + idx_b[0] * size[2]

    # map the two frames into a multiply-able form
    y1 = df1.values[idx_1, :]
    y2 = df2.values[idx_2, :]

    # multiply the to frames
    df4 = pd.DataFrame(y1 * y2, index=index, columns=columns[3:])
    return df4


def method3():
    dft = df2.swaplevel()
    dft.sortlevel(level=0,inplace=True)
    df5=pd.concat([df1*dft.loc[i,:] for i in dft.index.get_level_values('foobar').unique() ], keys=dft.index.get_level_values('foobar').unique().tolist(), names=['foobar'])
    df5=df5.reorder_levels(['greek', 'latin', 'foobar'],axis=0)
    df5.sortlevel(0,inplace=True)
    return df5


from timeit import timeit
print(timeit(method1, number=50))
print(timeit(method2, number=50))
print(timeit(method3, number=50))
```

**Results:**

```
4.089807642158121
0.12291539693251252
0.33667341712862253
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code without the for loops.  Basic idea is to expand the two matrices so that they are the same size and can be multiplied together.  Then multiply...

**Code:**

```
# build an index from the three index columns
idx = [df1.index.get_level_values(col).unique() for col in columns[:2]
       ] + [df2.index.get_level_values(columns[2]).unique()]
size = [len(x) for x in idx]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(idx, names=columns[:3])

# get the indices needed for df1 and df2
idx_a = np.indices((size[0] * size[1], size[2])).reshape(2, -1)
idx_b = np.indices((size[0], size[1] * size[2])).reshape(2, -1)
idx_1 = idx_a[0]
idx_2 = idx_a[1] + idx_b[0] * size[2]

# map the two frames into a multiply-able form
y1 = df1.values[idx_1, :]
y2 = df2.values[idx_2, :]

# multiply the two frames
df = pd.DataFrame(y1 * y2, index=index, columns=columns[3:])
```

**Test Data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = ['alpha', 'beta']
b = ['A', 'B', 'C']
c = ['foo', 'bar']
data_columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']
columns = ['greek', 'latin', 'foobar'] + data_columns

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(a) * len(b), len(data_columns)),
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                       [a,b], names=columns[0:2]),
                   columns=data_columns
                   )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
                             [1, 1, 1, 1],
                             [0, 0, 0, 0],
                             [0, 2, 0, 4],
                             ]),
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                       [a, c],
                       names=[columns[0], columns[2]]),
                   columns=data_columns
                   )
```

**Timing Code:**

```
def method1():
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    for i in df1.index.get_level_values('greek').unique():
            for j in df1.loc[i].index.get_level_values('latin').unique():
                for k in df2.loc[i].index.get_level_values('foobar').unique():
                    df3 = df3.append(pd.Series(
                        [i, j, k],
                        index=columns[:3]).append(
                        df1.loc[i, j] * df2.loc[i, k]), ignore_index=True)
    df3.set_index(columns[:3], inplace=True)
    return df3

def method2():
    # build an index from the three index columns
    idx = [df1.index.get_level_values(col).unique() for col in columns[:2]
           ] + [df2.index.get_level_values(columns[2]).unique()]
    size = [len(x) for x in idx]
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(idx, names=columns[:3])

    # get the indices needed for df1 and df2
    idx_a = np.indices((size[0] * size[1], size[2])).reshape(2, -1)
    idx_b = np.indices((size[0], size[1] * size[2])).reshape(2, -1)
    idx_1 = idx_a[0]
    idx_2 = idx_a[1] + idx_b[0] * size[2]

    # map the two frames into a multiply-able form
    y1 = df1.values[idx_1, :]
    y2 = df2.values[idx_2, :]

    # multiply the to frames
    df4 = pd.DataFrame(y1 * y2, index=index, columns=columns[3:])
    return df4

from timeit import timeit
print(timeit(method1, number=50))
print(timeit(method2, number=50))
```

**Results:**

```
7.96668368373
0.149504332128
```